# Display names of all XML files containing a particular string

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, string-parsing, stax

I'm trying to extract all the protocols containing a particular keyword from an xml file called MasterData.xml and then search each of those protocols in a folder named DataDefinition containing many xml files. I'm able to do the 1st part but having trouble in the 2nd part i.e searching for a particular protocol in many xml files.Please help..

MasterData.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004236">
<NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.SNMPV1-SSL</NAME>
<PROTOCOLTAG>SNMPV1:SSL</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004237">
<NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.SNMPV2-SSL</NAME>
<PROTOCOLTAG>SNMPV2:SSL</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004238">
<NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.BACNET-SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER-RS-485</NAME>
<PROTOCOLTAG>BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER/RS-485</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
<NetworkProtocolDefinition oid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000004239">
<NAME>res.dcim.networkprotocol.def.BACNET-SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED-RS-485</NAME>
<PROTOCOLTAG>BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED/RS-485</PROTOCOLTAG>
</NetworkProtocolDefinition>
</CDMDataXML>
```

Java Code..

```
  Integer files_no= null;
  File xml_files = new File("D:\\branches\\ENGINE-R3.2\\components\\ElementLibraries\\ElementLibraryPackages\\DataDefinition");
  files_no = xml_files.listFiles().length;

   String crits[] = new String [100];
   Integer i = 0;     
   Integer COUNTER = 0;
   XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
   XMLStreamReader rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("D:\\lucy\\MasterData\\MasterData.xml"));
   while (rdr.hasNext()) {
     if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
      if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("PROTOCOLTAG")) {
           String txt = rdr.getElementText();
           if (txt.contains("SITELINK")) {     // You can also use "txt.indexOf("SITELINK") > 0"
              System.out.println(txt);
              COUNTER++;
              crits[i]=txt;
              i++;
            }
       }
  }
 }
 System.out.println(COUNTER+"\n");
System.out.println(files_no);
```

So i want to search the below 2 protocols in all the XML files located at the folder DataDefinition and print the names of the files containing that particular protocol.

```
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-BREAKER/RS-485
 BACNET:SITELINK_W-LDM-SUBFEED/RS-485
```

Since some files in the folder have 30k lines i'm looking for a solution which consumes less memory.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, i will do that in two steps. 
1) Make a list of all the protocols found in the MasterData.xml file.
2) Create a map where the protocols are the keys, and the value will be a list of all the files containing this protocol.
And i will probably use XPath (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) to simplify the search.

Comment: Yes as you can see from my code above i'm able to do the 1st part. It's the second part i need help with..

Comment: somes hints i will do someting like that : 
1) initialize a Map where protocol is the key, and for each protocol initialize a List of String
1) for each file in the directory
2) open it, search for the protocols via Xpath
3) for each founded protocols, get the map element and add the filename to the list